# Inner Join and Group By in SQL with out an aggregate function.

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 table with some conditions. When I just do the inner join with the conditions , I get a huge value (200000 data). But when I group by I get a very less value like (8000 data).

```
SELECT Tcg.SK_tID, Tcg.SK_ServiceProviderID
INTO #CHDetails 
FROM #ClientGroup Tcg           
INNER JOIN dbo.Component AS chd ON  chd.SK_PID = Tcg.SK_PID 
                                AND chd.SK_ServiceProviderID = Tcg.SK_ServiceProviderID
                                AND chd.SK_CompID = @CHD
                                AND chd.ReportDate < @ReportDate
GROUP BY Tcg.SK_PID ,Tcg.SK_ServiceProviderID
```

Can you please let me know the cause for this. Inner join always takes the common data. 
The data in the #ClientGroup table is around 70000 , while data in the dbo.Component is very huge. When I query for common PID and Service provider logically it shoul give me the records equal to or less than #ClientGroup. How is it giving more ?

When I do group by i get 8000. But why should I do group by in a inner join for 2 tables.

Comment: What happens when you remove the group by clause?  My recent discovery is that the group by essentially works like a distinct clause.  What's your reason for using group by in this case, without an aggregate?

Comment: Yes you are right Group by makes it distinct. But logically the count of the records should be less than #ClientGroup table count. But i cam getting huge data like 200000 insted of some 8000 or the same as count of #ClientGroup (If it gets a match for all the records)

Comment: True, and I just realized I misread your question; my apologies. indio's answer seems to be the issue, but I'd have to see the schema of your tables.   What he's explaining is that your inner join may not be joined correctly.  something is providing more results than expected.  I'll look more into it and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

The group by is essentially performing a distinct on the result. The reason you have to do this is likely because you have duplicates in both tables.

See this sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cbdca/2

In it, table1 has 3 rows and table2 has 3 rows. When joined together, they return 9 rows.

Answer (score 0):

if a join is giving you more records than expected that means that your join criterea is not complete. The extreme case for this would be a cartesian join.

check your joining criteria.

Comment: Its inner join with a criteria . How can this go wrong. ? can you explain on your answer. Sorry i caould not get ur answer

Comment: in your instance, you joining criterea (chd.SK_PID = Tcg.SK_PID 
AND chd.SK_ServiceProviderID = Tcg.SK_ServiceProviderID) is generating dupplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Group by combines rows together.  Usually it is done to produce aggregate data or produce a list of unique values.  In your example, the #ClientGroup table is grouped together and the total number of rows you get returned shrinks.  You should be getting less rows than are in #ClientGroup.

Answer (score 0):

It will not reduce the number of rows because The INNER JOIN does not perform DISTINCT instead INNER JOIN finds all matching data from both tables.

Let’s say you have table A and table B. both has column ID.
Table A has total 3 rows in it and all values are unique. values are 1,2,3.
TABLE B has total 300 rows, but only 3 unique values. Values are 1,2,3. 
(table B has 100 rows for each unique value)

Now in this example if I do INNER JOIN between Table A  and Table B 
then **every row from A will get join Every matching row in table B**.
So 
value 1 from Table A will match 100 rows in table B
value 2 from Table A will match 100 rows in table B
value 3 from Table A will match 100 rows in table B

so after doing INNER join I will get total 300 rows.

On the contrary if Table B has completely different values (other than 1,2,3) then INNER JOIN would has produced no result.