# MySQL - Why would nearly 2 identical queries result in 2 different results? GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have 2 queries that are nearly identical, one with a GROUP BY, one without. The results are very different. The GROUP BY query results in over double the non-GROUP BY query result.

Query 1:

```
SELECT table2.name, COUNT(DISTINCT(op.id))
FROM op INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.EID = op.ID
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table1.jobid
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table3.CatID
WHERE op.BID = 1
    AND op.ActiveStartDate <= NOW()
    AND op.ActiveEndDate >= NOW()
GROUP BY table2.name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT op.Type, COUNT(DISTINCT op.id)
FROM op
WHERE op.BID = 1
AND op.ActiveStartDate <= NOW()
    AND op.ActiveEndDate >= NOW()
ORDER BY op.Type ASC;
```

These should result in the same result. When playing around with them, once I remove the "GROUP BY" from query 1, the result is the same. If I put the "GROUP BY" back into Query 1, the result is more than doubled.

Edit: It seems the additional INNER JOINS are not affecting the results, but rather the GROUP BY in query 1. If I remove the GROUP BY in query 1, the results between the 2 queries are identical. If I add the GROUP BY back into query 1, the results are very different.

Comment: Why would you expect these to be identical when the first query has joins to two additional tables?

Comment: the WHERE conditions are identical between the 2 queries, and I'm looking at the COUNT(DISTINCT op.id) as should be being the same result.... If the tables joined in query 1 are indeed accurate joins, why would the DISTINCT id counts be increased? Or, should I join the tables in the 2nd query, although unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you think that those are *nearly identical* queries; they are very different. Anyway, you shouldn't remove the `GROUP BY` from the first one, but add a `GROUP BY` on the second query:

```
SELECT op.Type, COUNT(DISTINCT op.id)
FROM op
WHERE op.BID = 1
AND op.ActiveStartDate <= NOW()
    AND op.ActiveEndDate >= NOW()
GROUP BY op.Type
ORDER BY op.Type ASC;
```

Of course, this doesn't mean that you'll get the same results anyway, since the first query has 3 extra joins.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd one does need the GROUP BY, although this did not change the result of the COUNT. Since COUNT(DISTINCT op.id) is identical in both queries, and the INNER JOINS are indeed accurate joins in the first, I'm not sure why adding those joins should change the result. Should the 2nd query have those joins too, although unnecessary?

Answer (score 0):

the queries are not at all "nearly identical..." in my view.
you have INNER JOIN with other tabls that can have duplicates and so the INNER JOIN will increase the number of rows by that number. 
you can check the explaination in here

[INNER JOIN and GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118267/inner-join-and-group-by-in-sql-with-out-an-aggregate-function/19124945#19124945)